# CRM 2011 Email Tracking

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there a way to tell in CRM 2011/ CRM 2013 whether the email was Promoted to CRM by the user manually by clicking on The Track in CRM button or if it was Promoted automatically based on the Personal Email Settings or the System Email Settings.

Case: We have multiple emails in Dynamics CRM and some of them have been promoted to CRM due to incorrect tracking options set in Outlook. There are also emails which the user has tracked manually by clicking on the Track in CRM button.
Is there a way to figure out which email was Tracked by Clicking the track button and which email was promoted due to Automatic tracking?

Comment: good question. one thing probably you can check is copy the 2 email records from database & compare the column values, to see if CRM is internally flagging it. but I dont find any documentation around your query in internet. 

I came across this interesting troubleshooting steps here -  https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/17427/27838#27838

Comment: @ArunVinoth Good suggestion. Let me try this out and see if I can find a difference.